# Jsfiddle won't work when copying into Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I've been trying to solve this by myself, and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. But this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3964w/3/ completely stops working when I try to work with it in Dreamweaver.

Here is my html code, if that helps. I'm feeling so lost on this, and I think it should be pretty easy. If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong I would be very grateful.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>testing jquery</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
  var offset = $('.container').offset();
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
   if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
   if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);

</script>    

</head>

<body>

<div class="centerdiv">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="follower"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling jQuery from a CDN or a local directory? If from a CDN it won't work unless the page is being run from a server, like localhost. So if you don't have a local server set up then download a copy of jQuery and put it inside the directory where you are putting JavaScript files and call it from there.

Or USe this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or  write your code inside document ready function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{ /* Your Code Here */ });
 </script>
```

Comment: I didn't know this. Why can't it be run via CDN without a local server? My understanding was that CDNs are there to put the resources online and give something to link to.

Comment: yeah it works but check the OP's CDN  link it's not correct  to  include the CDN  in the localhost,  need to use http://ajax. ... or https://ajax. I suggested possible two solution .

Comment: Ah, I understand now.

Comment: You probably should have put the `http://` correction as the first part of your answer, it's more likely that that is what OP's trying to do, and it's the more straightforward solution.

Comment: Ok, so I am still learning at this, so please be understanding. But I just wanted to call from a CDN, not using a local host. It still does not seem to be working for me for some reason...
I tried using the script source that you gave me to no avail. Is it possible that the jsfiddle code does not transfer well into Dreamweaver, causing it not to work?

Comment: yeah sometimes happens .oky you can try one thing download the library and add it without using cdn If it works then your code is okay issue will be cdn calling , but If doesn't work either then definitely problem will be for copying code from jsfiddle to dreamweaver

Comment: That is not working either unfortunately. I have been trying that after the first did not work.

Is there any way to understand why the code is not working? It just seems so strange to me that it works perfectly in jsfiddle but stops when taking it out...

Comment: did you add  <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag ?? or did you write your piece of code under                                   $("document").ready(function () {   //jquery code//  });                                cz jsfiddle put this under document ready function automatically.  the wole process will be like this                                                                                                                                                 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Your Code Here */  });
    </script>

Comment: Awesome!! It is working, thank you so much. 
I didn't have either of those things included.
I knew there was something I was missing just by not doing this before. Thanks for sticking with me :p

Answer (score 0):

style.css is missing, and

I will replace

`ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js`

by

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`